# Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS Adobe Flash Player

Tags: 12.04, google-chrome, flash, 32-bit

I have Adobe Flash Player installed on Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS 32-bit but there seems to be a few instances of the same player especially in Google Chrome. When I check through chrome://plugins/ I saw two entries and after I uninstalled by invoking the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove adobe-flashplugin 
sudo apt-get remove adobe-flash
sudo apt-get remove flashplugin-installer
sudo dpkg --purge flashplugin-installer
sudo apt-get remove --purge ubuntu-restricted-extras adobe-flashplugin flashplugin-installer
```

I still got an entry in chrome://plugins/ that can be identified in the following screenshot.
[image]

I would like to remove all instances of Flash Player and perform a clean reinstall, can you provide help on this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That flash is the one that is bundled with Google Chrome (and can only be used by Google Chrome). As such, you can't remove that without removing Chrome.

Comment: Well thanks for the answer. I think that flash is not used system wide and cannot be upgraded manually.

Comment: If you want a system-wide flash, you can install `flashplugin-installer` (for Flash 11.2, NPAPI) or use [this](https://launchpad.net/~skunk/+archive/pepper-flash) PPA (for Flash 13.0, PPAPI, currently only used by Chromium).

Answer (score 1):

The Ubuntu Software Center should have the ability to uninstall this plugin. If not, I would recommend using Synaptic. It is a great software manager. Ubuntu used to use this manager; however, like other Ubuntu software, it was discontinued in later OS distros. Both are user friendly, unlike command line.

Comment: But the system does not see two distinct players.